# How to shorten a long url containing meta data, to work within a javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-fields

Got a wordpress blog with tons of posts fully built by custom fields.

I'm now working on header.php file

I'm building a javascript including a window.open url containing the mentioned custom fields.

This url is so long, and is going to be repeated over 20 times within the script.

I'm then looking for a way to define the the whole url within a single string $long_url within the header.php file (I can't use goo.gl or bit.ly etc. for obvious reasons, since the url calls custom fields)

So, current script says...

```
window.open
http://website.com/?value1=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'value1', true); ?>&value2=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'value2', true); ?>&value3=etc...
```

I want to replace the mentioned url with a single string...

```
window.open
$long_url
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `$long_url = "http://website.com/?value1=" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'value1', true); . "&value2=" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'value2', true); ."&value3=etc..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the PHP variable inside the JavaScript string.

```
<?php $long_url = 'http://website.com/?value1=' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'value1', true) . '&value2='. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'value2', true);?>
window.open("<?=$long_url?>");
```